# Pandas (key, value) data, move duplicate instance of key's value into a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns 'NAME' and 'VALUE':

```
NAME       VALUE
apple        6
banana       3
cherry       7
apple        2
banana       5
cherry       3
```

I would like to move the duplicate instances' VALUE to a new column as such:

```
NAME       VALUE VALUE2
apple        6     2
banana       3     5
cherry       7     3
```

I have done this in Python previously by iterating through CSV rows and maintaining a unique list of NAME's read so far, checking for the existence of NAME in the list...if it is, then it's now the 2nd time I've seen it so I add its VALUE to the new column VALUE2.  By the way, the rows are not assumed to be in any particular order.

Is there a quick way of doing this in Pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We'll need two `set_index` calls plus an `unstack`:

```
df = df.set_index('NAME').set_index(
    df.groupby('NAME').cumcount(), append=True
).unstack()   

df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format)
```

```
df
        VALUE0  VALUE1
NAME                  
apple        6       2
banana       3       5
cherry       7       3
```

Comment: I'm curious about how did you know how to 'chain' all these methods to achieve that result. Is it based on your experiences with `pandas` or is there a comprehensive reference that you don't mind to share? Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic!  @coldspeed answered just a hair before but both theirs and Wen's solutions work.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Anthony my comprehensive reference involves all the questions that I've answered over the months :-)

Comment: Gotcha, i’m still learning how to use pandas effectively too, i’ll check on your profile about your posts. Cheers!

Comment: @Robert I'd recommend opening a new question. Can you do that?

Comment: I had a question earlier on reshaping the resulting dataset (reset the indexes) - I believe it would be a duplicate question now and I think I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 5):

By using `pivot`

```
df.assign(key=df.groupby('NAME').cumcount()+1).pivot('NAME','key','VALUE').add_prefix('VALUE_')
Out[397]: 
key     VALUE_1  VALUE_2
NAME                    
apple         6        2
banana        3        5
cherry        7        3
```